Do you need to damage Pyramid Head in your first fight with him?
In the original Silent Hill 2, your first fight with Pyramid Head was a timed encounter. After a few minutes he just leaves, and you can move on. Damaging him will reduce the length of the fight, but the fight will still end even if you don't damage him at all. Does the first fight in the 2024 remake work the same way?
Will the first fight with Pyramid Head end after a few minutes even if you never damage him?

Posting this since I was wondering if the fight worked the same way as the original, and I figured I wasn't the only one. I just decided to experiment and wait it out, but posting this for anyone else that would rather not just find out for themselves.

You don't need to damage him. You just need to survive a few minutes and you'll win this fight. I confirmed this myself by not damaging him at all, and the fight ended automatically after a few minutes. Additionally, according to multiple sources online, damaging him will still end the fight earlier, just like it did in the original.
